# Only admin enters a page

Tags: php, session, admin

This is my signin.php file

and I want to make a page which only admin (mousoufi) can enter.
I made a new page where I want to post only admin things can see. Else I wanted to echo to other users that they dont have permission here. 
I just make a session on top of my admin page?

Any  ideas?

```
<?php
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","3333");
if (!$con)
 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}



$sql = "SELECT username FROM `3333` WHERE password='$pass' AND       username='$user'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
         // outputdata of each row
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo "You are now logged in " . $row["username"]."<br>";
     }
 }
 else {
     echo "Wrong Password Try Again"; }

 // Set session variables
 $_SESSION["username"] = "$user";
 $_SESSION["password"] = "$pass";
 print_r($_SESSION);

if ("$user"=="mousoufi" AND "$pass"=="1234"){
echo "HELLO Mousoufi ";
}


$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: exactly what is your question ... also you have to put session_start(); at the top of your page after <?php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use sessions you need to start them on **every single page** that you need them on, and that is done with this:

```
session_start();
```

Put that at the top of your php script.

You'll need a way to distinguish admins (*if you're going to have more than one?*), but since your question only states one, this should work for you:

```
<?php
// start session
session_start();
// check if username is admin
if($_SESSION['username'] !== 'mousoufi'){
    // isn't admin, redirect them to a different page
    header("Location: /someotherpage.php");
}
```

---

**Notes**

- You should have more readable table names. `3333` isn't really the best, especially when you call the table the same thing...
- You should at least sanitize your user input variables - [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) at very least. It'd be best if you go with `PDO` or `MySQLi Prepared Statements`.

Your script is wrong, badly wrong. If your user didn't log in correctly, don't set the session.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 0) {
     die("Wrong Password Try Again";);
} else {
     // outputdata of each row
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo "You are now logged in " . $row["username"]."<br>";
         $_SESSION['username'] = $row["username"];
         // and so on...
     }
}
```

This is what your block should look like.

Comment: I tried it, also I wanted to show the logged in users on top of my page and I used this session <!--session-->
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   echo $_SESSION['username'];
   echo"<a href='logout.php'>LogOut</a>";
}
else
{
  header("header:index.php?notify=Something went wrong!!");
}
?>
<li><a href="#">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></a></li>
<!--session-->, but it doesnt work I am learning php this semester and I can not the error